# Change Field Level Security on Custom Web Tabs?

Tags: tab, field-level-security

I created a custom web tab:

`SF>Setup>Build>Create>Tabs>Web Tabs>New`:

And after it's created, when I go to Edit it, I can't change the visibility or field level security.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround but directly you can not edit the visibility by editing the tab. Refer the below idea created which tells:-

> So I create a tab and forget to give permissions to a handful of
>   profiles.  "Oh well, I figure, I can go back and do that part later."
>       You'd think I could go to the Tab settings and make it "Default On", "Default Off" or "Tab Hidden" for the handful of profiles from
>   the Tab itself.  Nope.  I have to go to EVERY profile and edit the
>   tab's permisions there!
>       That stinks and is super annoying!
>       Please let me edit the tab visibility from the tab's settings.
>       **The work-around is to delete and recreate the tab. Ick!**

Another similar idea has been created :-

> We have many business cases where an Admin has a need to either mass
>   update the Visibility of one or more Tabs to be Default On, Off or
>   Hidden across many Profiles and it would be really nice to be able to
>   perform these mass updates in the native UI rather than having to go
>   out to a Tool like the IDE.

As of now, workaround is go to each profile and make the changes in Tab permission.

Reference:-

1. [Let me modify Tab visibility from the Tab Settings](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000HUNfAAO)
2. [Ability to Mass Update Visibility of Tabs](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000lBEPAA2)
3. [View and Edit Tab Settings in Permission Sets and Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_tab_visibility.htm&type=5)